# android camera intent crashes app on some phones (about 20% of them)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have done a lot of researching into this issue and have seen some great responses and found some good resources of "solutions" to this problem.  Unfortunately however, I'm still encountering a lot of app crashes on certain devices.  The crashes occur after someone has taken their photo and the camera intent is supposed to pass the info back to the calling activity.  For the purposes of my app, I'm just overwriting any existing photo with the newly taken photo so I can use pretty much a static path to the file location.  Here's how I call the intent:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // get the file path from an external class (necessary for galaxy nexus)
        imageFileAndPath = ImageServices.getOutputImageFileUri(cont);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileAndPath);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

the imageFileAndPath is just a URI variable and I am creating it from a separate class because that resolved another issue where pressing "done" or the checkmark or w/e it is on the particular device to close the camera intent wasn't doing anything on several device types.  By creating the URI from a separate class, it resolves that issue for some unknown reason.

my onActivityResult looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            setupImageView();
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            reTakePicButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
        }
    }
}
```

because I don't need a dynamic path to save my photos (since it is overwriting existing photos), I just call another method within my activity that resizes the photo and rotates it accordingly.  That method is below:

```
private void setupImageView() {     
    imageLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myappphoto/myappphoto.jpg";


    // Get the dimensions of the View
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = getDisplaySize(display);
    int targetW = size.x;

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetW);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation, bmOptions);
    int rotationForImage = getRotationForImage(imageLocation);
    if (rotationForImage != 0) {
        int targetWidth = rotationForImage == 90 || rotationForImage == 270 ? bitmap.getHeight() : bitmap.getWidth();
        int targetHeight = rotationForImage == 90 || rotationForImage == 270 ? bitmap.getWidth() : bitmap.getHeight();




        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, bitmap.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(rotatedBitmap);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRotate(rotationForImage, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, new Paint());

        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = rotatedBitmap;

    }



    Bitmap resized;

    if(bitmap.getWidth() >= 900 || bitmap.getHeight() >=900)
    {
        int newWidth = Math.round(bitmap.getWidth()/2);
        int newHeight = Math.round(bitmap.getHeight()/2);
        resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
    }
    else
    {
        resized = bitmap;
    }
    //bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = resized;


    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bytes);

    try
    {
        File f = new File(imageLocation);
        f.createNewFile();
        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    }
    catch(java.io.IOException e){}
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

you can see the static path at the top of that method to the image file that is saved from the camera intent.

I suppose it's possible that the resizing, rotation method is causing the crashes, but I don't see why it would, that all looks like pretty standard java coding to me.

Can anyone see anything glaringly wrong with what I'm doing here?  As I said in the title of this thread, my code is causing crashes on about 20% of the devices that run it which is unacceptable.  I can handle 5% but not 20%.

I realize that android development is somewhat of a nightmare in this regard because you have to account for so many different device types (manufacturers, versions of android etc), but I would think the camera activity should be better standardized than this.  As I said at the top of this thread, I have done a LOT of looking into this issue and seen several people with similar issues to mine but no good resolution that covers most devices.  I really don't want to have to write (nor do I think I should have to write) my own camera from ground zero.  There has to be a better implementation of the default, built-in camera intent on android devices...I just haven't been able to find it yet.  As you can see, I'm not even concerned with dynamically creating images which should make this project a ton easier.

TIA

Edit: per the comment below, I have added a stacktrace from a failing camera.  It looks like a null pointer exception.  I took like 6 pictures, and kept going back using the button that calls the camera intent until finally got it to fail.  Here's the stack trace:

```
STACK_TRACE
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.myapp/com.myapp.MyActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=904, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.myapp/com.myapp.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=904, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.myapp/com.myapp.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myapp.MyActivity.onActivityResult(EnterContest.java:257)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
    ... 14 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=904, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.myapp/com.myapp.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myapp.MyActivity.onActivityResult(EnterContest.java:257)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
    ... 14 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myapp.MyActivity.onActivityResult(EnterContest.java:257)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post relevant stack traces showing the nature of your "crashes".

Comment: @CommonsWare unfortunately I don't have them to post.  The crashes are happening on devices with which I can not test.  This app is currently in a beta phase and some of the users are experiencing the crashes, while most are not.  How can I set up logging to obtain stack trace information from devices that are already "in the field" that are crashing

Comment: "How can I set up logging to obtain stack trace information from devices that are already "in the field" that are crashing" -- use ACRA or similar libraries: http://acra.ch.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok I posted a stack trace in my OP.  Why would it work several times, and then get a NPE?

Comment: Your stack trace does not match your source code. There is no line directly in the `onActivityResult()` that you have here that could raise a `NullPointerException`. You are running some other implementation of `onActivityResult()`, and we have no way of knowing what that might contain, let alone why it might be crashing.

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right, I omitted some of my onActivityResult() stuff because I didn't think it was the culprit.  It's mostly just showing / hiding elements on the xml layout.  Those elements are declared at the top of my activity (class) as fields.  Could those field values be lost during the camera intent?  Thus when it returns to the calling activity, they are now null? thanks very much for your time on this.  I've updated my OP with the rest of the stuff in the onActivityResult() method.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a guess but I think I had the same problem, I fixed it reading the bitmap in a new AsyncTask and not in the UI thread.

The exception happened (apparently in a random way) calling

```
getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
```

where selectedImage is the URI set before in

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
```

What were you calling in com.myapp.MyActivity.onActivityResult(EnterContest.java:257) ?

I have a stack trace collected with ACRA:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.infonair.meetme.app/com.infonair.meetme.activity.photo.TakePhotoActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=7898789, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/9 }} to activity {com.infonair.meetme.app/com.infonair.meetme.activity.photo.TakePhotoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2141)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2838)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3737)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:894)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=7898789, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/9 }} to activity {com.infonair.meetme.app/com.infonair.meetme.activity.photo.TakePhotoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2538)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.notifyChange(IContentService.java:458)
at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:912)
at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:898)
at com.infonair.meetme.activity.photo.TakePhotoActivity.onActivityResult(TakePhotoActivity.java:154)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2534)
... 14 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=7898789, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/9 }} to activity {com.infonair.meetme.app/com.infonair.meetme.activity.photo.TakePhotoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2538)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2141)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2838)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3737)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:894)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.notifyChange(IContentService.java:458)
at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:912)
at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:898)
at com.infonair.meetme.activity.photo.TakePhotoActivity.onActivityResult(TakePhotoActivity.java:154)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2534)
... 14 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.notifyChange(IContentService.java:458)
at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:912)
at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:898)
at com.infonair.meetme.activity.photo.TakePhotoActivity.onActivityResult(TakePhotoActivity.java:154)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2534)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2141)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2838)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3737)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:894)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I'm having this very problem. Several devices (all of them SG) crash randomly when using this intent, same line (getContent().notifyChange(uri,null) ) with a nullpointerexception.

Comment: @Frank have you tried to use an AsyncTask to do the operation ?

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with this issue I noticed that in some devices the picture taken was way too big even to be displayed on an ImageView (there was a warning about the image being too wide for texture), so I began working on resizing it to a server-usable size.

I'll post the whole code (at least the one regarding taking and manipulating the picture) just in case it may help

Here's the code to call the intent

```
 public void takePhoto() {

      String directoryPath = DCIM_PATH;
      this.pictureFileName = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg";
      String filePath = directoryPath + pictureFileName ;
      File directory = new File(directoryPath);

      if (!directory.exists()) {
          directory.mkdirs();
       }

       this.imageUri = Uri.parse(filePath);
       Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       intent.putExtra( 
             MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile( new File(filePath) )
       );

       startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

 }
```

in `onActivityResult` I call a method to deal with the newly taken picture

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAKE_PICTURE:
               if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                           loadImageJustTaken(imageUri);
               }
            break;
        }
 }
```

**This is said method**

```
public void loadImageJustTaken(Uri selectedImage) {

        mActivity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
        /*
         * process image to make its wide equals IMG_WIDTH constant, so that larger images will fit in ImageView
         */

         Bitmap b = BitmapHelper.decodeFileToScaledBitmap(new File(imageUri.getPath()), Tapabook.IMG_WIDTH);
        ivPicture.setImageBitmap(b);
        ivPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        System.gc(); 
 }
```

**And here is the code for my** `BitmapHelper` **class**

```
public class BitmapHelper {


    private static final String LOGTAG = "BitmapHelper";

    public static File scaleBitmapFile(File f, int WIDTH) throws IOException{
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "scaleBitmapFile to WIDTH: " + WIDTH);

            Bitmap b2 = decodeFileToScaledBitmap( f, WIDTH);
            ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "scaleBitmapFile compress bitmap to jpg ");
            b2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,70 , outStream);

            File scaledBitmapFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "temp.jpg");
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "scaleBitmapFile file: temp.jpg" );
            scaledBitmapFile.createNewFile();
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "scaleBitmapFile file CREATED" );
            //write the bytes in file
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(scaledBitmapFile);
            fo.write(outStream.toByteArray());
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "scaleBitmapFile file WRITTEN" );
            // remember close de FileOutput
            fo.close();
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "scaleBitmapFile file CLOSED" );

            return scaledBitmapFile;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeFileToScaledBitmap(File f, int WIDTH){
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "decodeFileToScaledBitmap to WIDTH: " + WIDTH);
            try{
                    //Decode image size
                    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

                    //The new size we want to scale to
                    final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;

                    final int ORIG_WIDTH  = o.outWidth;
                    final int ORIG_HEIGHT = o.outHeight;
                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "decodeFileToScaledBitmap original width: [" + ORIG_WIDTH + "] original height: [" + ORIG_HEIGHT+ "]");
                    final int REQUIRED_HEIGHT = ORIG_HEIGHT/( ORIG_WIDTH / REQUIRED_WIDTH ) ;

                    //Decode with scaled height
                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "decodeFileToScaledBitmap returning scaled bitmap ");
                    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath()), 
                                    REQUIRED_WIDTH, 
                                    REQUIRED_HEIGHT, 
                                    false);
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e(LOGTAG, "decodeFileToScaledBitmap FileNotFoundException: " +e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
    }

    public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap b, int WIDTH){
            final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;

            final int ORIG_WIDTH  = b.getWidth();
            final int ORIG_HEIGHT = b.getHeight();
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "scaleBitmap original width: [" + ORIG_WIDTH + "] original height: [" + ORIG_HEIGHT+ "]");
            final int REQUIRED_HEIGHT = ORIG_HEIGHT/( ORIG_WIDTH / REQUIRED_WIDTH ) ;
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "scaleBitmap returning scaled bitmap ");
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                            b, 
                            REQUIRED_WIDTH, 
                            REQUIRED_HEIGHT, 
                            false); 
    }
}
```

Using this I no longer have issues when taking pictures with Samsung devices, either old handhelds like SG3/Apollo or newer tablets like SGTab 10.1
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

See this post here
[Content uri crashes camera on Android KitKat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087944/content-uri-crashes-camera-on-android-kitkat)

Some older camera applications do not properly support content:// URIs and will crash when passed an EXTRA_OUTPUT that is not a file:// URI.  I noticed this bug when updating my code to support FileProviders in Android N+.  If you change the URI to be a file:// URI for applications with SDK less than Android N, you should be able to resolve this issue.