# Content uri crashes camera on Android KitKat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-fileprovider

I run into problem while using content uri and FileProvider on Android API 19 (Kitkat). Here's code that I use to open camera on device and record a video:

```
File file = new File(pathname);
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY_STRING, file);

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

I've tested this code on API's 23-24 and it works just fine, but on API 19 camera closes with RESULT_CANCELED after I starting to take video in camera app.
The same thing happening when I'm trying to take a picture with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE action.
I've tried to change FileProvider.getUriForFile() with Uri.fromFile(). This works perfectly on Kitkat, but I can't use it on Android 7.
Why is Camera on Adnroid Kitkat doesn't want to work with content uri?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every camera app will support `content` `Uri` values for `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, though they should. But, there are thousands of camera apps, and some percentage will fail on such a `Uri`. For example, until this summer, Google's own camera app did not support a `content` `Uri` for `EXTRA_OUTPUT` for `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`.

Either stop using `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` or live with unreliable results.

If you wish to try continuing to use `file` `Uri` values, drop your `targetSdkVersion` to 23 or lower, or disable the `FileUriExposedException` by changing the `StrictMode` configuration.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.

Comment: So if I want to have API 24 as targetSdkVersion and to keep using content Uri, there is no way I can prevent this error on some devices?

Comment: @Yenn: You cannot force camera app developers to support `content` `Uri` values, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 17):

maybe you can try this one.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(mTmpFile);
    } else {
        fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                getContext().getPackageName()+".provider",mTmpFile);
    }
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks